# Did Mest have a guild mark?

Tags: fairy-tail

With respect to the recent questions about guild marks, there seems to be an important piece of information missing.

A main purpose of a guild mark should be to identify who is part of a guild. When Mest infiltrated fairy tail, did he have a guild mark? Could he have faked a guild mark?

My impression is that he merely had to cover enough of his skin with cloths so they assume his mark is hidden as no one would think to check.

Comment: Note that the purpose of my phrasing the title the way it was was to not indicate the infiltration in the title.  I don't know where others are in the anime/manga.

Comment: I don't think he really need a Guild Mark, as he could easily manipulate everyone's memory's to make it seem like he had already got one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do to recent reveals in the manga, it was revealed that he was a member of fairy tail and has a mark on his shoulder, he erased his own memories of fairy tail so he could infiltrate the council, so at the time he was infiltrating for the council he was actually acting as a double spy without him knowing

[image]

Comment: You can improve this answer by posting the picture of him with the said guild mark. Just suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

No, Mest Gryder did not have a Fairy Tail Guild mark. And neither did he need one. As his ability which allowed him to infiltrate to begin with can also cover for the lack of a guild mark. Allowing him to be a Fairy Tail member, without a Fairy Tail mark.

> Doranbolt, a member of the Magic councel, used Memory Control to deceive everyone in Fairy Tail into believing he was a member of their guild named Mest Gryder.

**Edit**

Is it a speculation? Mainly yes but do consider the following. His power allows him to make everybody think he is a guild member. To obtain a real guild emblem he would need to go to Makarov and ask for one. Which at that time already should think that he is a member of fairy tail. Which would make it weird for him to ask for a guild mark.

Comment: I also suspect that wouldn't need one and included that in the question but that does not mean he did not have one. Is there anything supporting your conclusion or is it, like mine, speculation? Either way I think you are correct.

Comment: @kaine see edit

Comment: Uhm do to recent reveals in the manga this answer doesn't hold true meaning anymore, it was revealed that he was a member of fairy tail and has a mark on his shoulder, he erased his own memories of fairy tail so he could infiltrate the council, so at the time he was infiltrating for the council he was actually acting as a double spy without him knowing.

Comment: @Wouter If you would like, that is an appropriate answer. If you write that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes he have guild mark, as per [Wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Mest_Gryder)

> After Tartaros' defeat, Fairy Tail's guild mark is given back to him
>   by Makarov; it rests on his right shoulder.

And here's his guild mark

[image]